# How to detect if an image is square?

Tags: image-processing, language-agnostic, scaling

I am making a desktop image editing software using `Processing`. It will allow the user to select the image to edit. The area in which the user can do the editing is a fixed `640 x 480` screen.

This means that I will have to scale the input image to fit the screen. That is easy to do with rectangular images. The problem arises when dealing with square images.
Programatically, `2500x2501` is not a square image. For all practical purposes it is.

How do I make sure that I properly scale these images ?

Comment: calculate the aspect ratio and using a threshold, decide whether it is around 1.

Comment: You could check if the values are within 0.1 percent of each other or some other small percentage and if they are, make each side the the average of the two values.  Never actually tested this, it just came to me while I was reading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the aspect ratio (width / height, or vice-versa). I suggest dividing whichever is smaller by the other one, so you always get a number that is no greater than one.

Then define a threshold, as a number between 0 and 1. If the resulting division gives a result smaller than the threshold, you can consider the image a non-square.

Comment: Worked with your example. Works wonderfully well.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines...

```
var ratio = 1;
if(Height>Width)
{
  ratio = (Height / Width);
}else{
  ratio = (Width / Height);
}

var ThresHoldVal = 0.1; // 10% out.

if((Ratio-1) > ThresholdVal)
{
  //Invalid.
}
```